# How to set default value for HTML select element that is submited by sql query?

Tags: sql, html

I`ve been struggling with this for a while

Address is visible for:

```
<select id='c_address_rule' name='address_rule' />
    <option value='2'>Everybody</option>
<option value='0'>Nobody</option>
<option value='1'>Registered </option>
</select>
```

I have this select element and

```
$address_rule=($result[0]['address_rule']);
```

And I can not think of a way to set `selected="selected"` to the option that have the `value == $address_rule`

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Just for my understanding: You want to query a database using php and in case no selection has been choosen by the user you want to use a default selection value?

Comment: Yes. My default value is 2, I`m creating the user interface atm and I need this so the user is able to see choose and change who can see his contact information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#c_address_rule").val($result[0]['address_rule']);
})
```

**PHP**

```
<select id='c_address_rule' name='address_rule' />
   <option value='2' <?php echo ($result[0]['address_rule'] == 2 ) ? selected="selected" : "" ?> >Everybody</option>
   <option value='0' <?php echo ($result[0]['address_rule'] == 0 ) ? selected="selected" : "" ?> >Nobody</option>
   <option value='1' <?php echo ($result[0]['address_rule'] == 1 ) ? selected="selected" : "" ?> >Registered </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

selected = "selected" means that you that value is selected.
when you load the form the where ever you have written selected = "selected"  you will get that value

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($address_rule == '1')
  {
    ?>
    <select id='c_address_rule' name='address_rule' />
      <option value='2'>Everybody</option>
      <option value='0'>Nobody</option>
      <option value='1' selected="selected">Registered </option>
    </select>
    <?php
   }
else if ($address_rule == '0')
  {
    ?>
    <select id='c_address_rule' name='address_rule' />
      <option value='2'>Everybody</option>
      <option value='0' selected="selected">Nobody</option>
      <option value='1' >Registered </option>
    </select>
    <?php
   }
```

go on....

Answer (score 0):

You can combine it with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#c_address_rule option").each(function(){
    if($this.attr("value")==<?php $yourresult;?>)
    $this.attr("selected","selected");
  });
});
```